# How to change number decimal format on ngx numbers cards

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, ngx-charts

I have an issue with formating the numbers shown on my chart. I am using the Number Card Chart and all the decimal are seperated by "." i want them to be seperated with the ",". So basically I have to change the language or locale to some european format... how and where and is this even possible? I have been looking at the documentation and their github issues but all I have found is the date formatting guide...

Is it possible to change/format numbers aswell and if so, how?

I have read about the `xAxisTickFormatting` and `yAxisTickFormatting` but my chart doesent use x&y axis...

Here is the code of my chart:

```
<ngx-charts-number-card
   [scheme]="colorScheme"
   [results]="financeChart"
   [cardColor]="cardColor">
</ngx-charts-number-card>
```

some.component.ts

```
colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#004799', '#f96605', '#0c65b8', '#fa8602', '#1376ca', '#fa9800', '#1b87dc', '#fbaa00', '#2195ea', '#fbb800', '#43a4ed', '#fcc224', '#64b4ef', '#fdce4c', '#90c9f4', '#fedb7f', '#bbdef8', '#fee9b1', '#e3f2fc', '#fff7e0']
  };
cardColor: string = '#FFFFFF';
```